# Is it possible to change Sony Vaio S13 harddisk to SSD?

Tags: ssd

I'm going to buy Sony Vaio S13, but I don't like slow harddisks, is it possible to buy for example Intel X25-M and change it to harddisk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that will be possible, as laptops use 2.5" SATA hard drives, the SSD will fit in exactly where the hard drive starts.

Normally, it will be very easy to install it, you will just have to find the cover for the hard drive section, remove it (phillips head screw driver) and swap the drives.

I have done this in my laptop (Samsung) and it worked perfectly, it gave a massive improvement, much more than adding extra RAM.